# Case Statement In Update Query

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

This works in SQL Server, but anytime I try to run it in my powershell environment it gives me an error of incorrect syntax near d.  What must I alter in order to have this run in powershell?

```
Function Run-Query
{
    param([string[]]$queries)

        $server='Server'
        $dbname='Database'
        $connStr='Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=SSPI;' -f $server,$dbname
        For ($i = 0; $i -lt $queries.count; $i++)
        {
            $Command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            $conn=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connStr)
            $conn.Open()            
            $Command.Connection = $conn
            $Command.CommandText=$queries[$i]
            $Command.ExecuteNonQuery() 
            $conn.Close()
        }
}

$updatequery = "UPDATE d
                 SET [updatedate] = GETDate(),
                 [shipped] =
                         (
                            CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(Select 1 *
                                                 from [server].[db].[dbo].[viewname] vw
                                                 WHERE vw.customername = d.customername)                    
                                THEN 'Yes'
                            ELSE
                                'PreviousCustomer'
                            END
                         )
                 FROM $fulllocation
                 WHERE ([shipped] IS NULL) 
                 AND ([managerapproved] IS NOT NULL)  
                 AND [readytoship] IN ('Go', 'Ready', 'Send')"


 Run-Query -queries $updatequery
```

Comment: Why `+=`? Did you define an empty array first? You may want to try making the string verbatim using the `@"my string"` syntax.

Comment: @arco444 - no that was just a typo on my part.  Removing it still throws the same error.

Comment: I hope it's fixed. one of the way I use to do this task is after running a query on SQL Server save the que query on a file then get the query into variable with a command
$query= get-content  PATH TO QUERY FILE   -Delimiter "{FIM}"

I add the delimiter for it to Grab the content until the end of file as one string not array of string

SQL Server 2012 and later come with SQLPS Module which include Invoke-SqlCmd command. 

There is one specific reason to create this function??

If you would like to use this approach tell me I will send you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your query as a string literal like this:

```
$updatequery = @"
                     UPDATE d
                     SET [updatedate] = GETDate(),
                     [shipped] =
                             (
                                CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(Select 1 
                                                     from [server].[db].[dbo].[viewname] vw
                                                     WHERE vw.customername = d.customername)                    
                                    THEN 'Yes'
                                ELSE
                                    'PreviousCustomer'
                                END
                             )
                     FROM $fulllocation
                     WHERE ([shipped] IS NULL) 
                     AND ([managerapproved] IS NOT NULL)  
                     AND [readytoship] IN ('Go', 'Ready', 'Send')
"@
```

Comment: of course I had to add in the * from the select statement for it to work properly.  Thought I would add for anyone else stumbling upon this.